# Comparar repositórios remotos

Tags: git, github, diff

Tenho no git um código em que meus colegas clonaram e me enviaram pull requests, porém acho que tem código duplicado entre eles.

Eu adicionei os repositórios deles na minha máquina e quero comparar um arquivo de diferentes repositórios.

Exemplo: comparar o arquivo `Arduino/main/main.ino` do repositório remoto "fulano" com o mesmo arquivo do repositório remoto "bertrano".

Comment: Sugiro baixar uma ferramenta como a WinMerge e usá-lá para comparar as pastas raízes de cada clone. Poderá visualizar a comparação entre cada arquivo das subpastas.

Comment: Não uso Windows. :(
Estava tentando diferenciar com o próprio comando `git diff` e utilizando o código dos commit's consegui diferenciar todos os arquivos entre eles (os commit's ), infelizmente não consegui, não somente um arquivo como esperava.
Soluciona por enquanto até porque tinha dois arquivos diferentes entre eles, mas ainda vou pesquisar uma solução como quero, arquivo por arquivo.

Comment: Se deseja apenas comparar arquivos, linha por linha, recomendo utilizar o [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/). Uma ferramenta de visual diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git diff remote1/branch remote2/branch file.rb
```

Sendo `remote1` e `remote2` o nome dos repositórios remotos, e `branch` a branch de Git que quer comprar. [Veja a documentação do `git-diff`.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: Foi o que fiz, embora esse comando diferencie todos os arquivos de branch.
o que eu queria era comparar apenas um arquivo.

Comment: @ViniciusdeSantana pode utilizar o git diff path/to/file.rb. Veja minha edição.

Comment: Até o momento estava utilizando a maneira anterior que compara todos os arquivos, depois do projeto que originou a pergunta poucas foram as vezes que precisei comparar arquivos (veja, estamos em março) mas estou prestes a entrar em um novo projeto em grupo e irei utilizar essa solução, obrigado.